# Strapi toObject() is not a function error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, strapi

I am trying to execute a custom query in strapi by following the documentation on
https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/concepts/queries.html#custom-queries

However I keep running into the error that the toObject function is not defined

**My approach:**

```
const result = strapi.query('balance').model.find({
          _id: "5f319bd650d74b153c8329dd",
        });
        console.log(result)
        const fields = result.toObject()
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError: result.toObject is not a function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you shouldn't need to use a .toObject() but you do need to make the query an async/await.

Comment: Thanks it worked. When are we supposed to use toObject() though?

Comment: Also can you highlight that the await was missing i guess so that it'll become a lill more clearer for anybody else visiting